# linking 2 lists

Tags: issue-tracking

Guys im trying to set up a calibration list using the issue list type in share point.  The team who will manage this list need to be able to select an address from a list when creating the item as opposed to inputing the address every time.  Is it possible to link to another list and have a drop down column from which to select the address from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Lookup column in one list that pulls data from another list.  This will automatically create a drop down of values the user can select from.

Answer (score 0):

my friend... It is a very basic sharepoint question. In sharepoint we call this lookup field. watch this video. is this what you are looking for?
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gIfCsSGDP1o

or read 
http://phase2.com/blog/?p=101

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out as I think its what your asking for? you can either pull the data from the database that the origional list you want to show in the drop down and bind it to the dropdownlist in spgridview like this:

http://dotnetknowledgebox.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/bind-dropdownlist-in-gridview.html

or

do the following:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        using (SPSite site = new ("http://yoursharepointsite"))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList list = web.Lists["NameOfYourList"];
                dropSite.DataSource = list.Items;
                dropSite.DataValueField = "Title"; // List field holding value - first column is called Title anyway!
                dropSite.DataTextField = "Title"; // List field holding name to be displayed on page 
                dropSite.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

this was taken from:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattlind/archive/2008/02/12/bind-a-asp-dropdownlist-to-a-sharepoint-list.aspx

Hope this helps you :)